# How can I obtain and save row into csv depending of a column value of csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, row

I am trying to use python to do a task and a I am a starter with python. I have big csv file in which I have to divide in different csv files depending in the value of a specific column. For example all rows that contain Red value in the colour column, save it in one csv file; if have blue value, save the rows containing it in a different csv file.

As I said, it is a big csv file in which the column I want to filter has quite a few values that differ from each other, so writing all the value will be tedious but if there is no other way, won´t be a problem.

Does anybody know how to do this task?

Example:

```
name  age colour grade
John  15  Red     8
Lucy  14  Blue    7
Katty 15  Red     9
Rob   16  Green   6
Mike  14  Blue    10
```

Solution:

```
red_colour.csv
name  age colour grade
John  15  Red     8
Katty 15  Red     9

green_colour.csv
name  age colour grade
Rob   16  Green   6

blue_colour.csv
name  age colour grade
Lucy  14  Blue    7
Mike  14  Blue    10
```

EDIT: I have used the code, but I don´t know why I am getting an error at reading the file. I am reading it in a RedHat machine.

```
# python3.6 example_read.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example_read.py", line 3, in <module>
    df = pandas.read_csv('/home/usrlogr/lista_blanca.csv')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 429, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1122, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1853, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 387, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 705, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'/home/usrlogr/lista_blanca.csv' does not exist: b'/home/usrlogr/lista_blanca.csv'
```

Does anybody know what is the problem? I have Python 3.6.8 and Pandas installed

Comment: I recommend the pandas package in python for this task.

Comment: hellow, please try it and let us know if you have an error on the script.  You can filter your data into red, green and blue then save it as csv file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all different colors in your data.  Then filter each row based on that color. Lastly, save into a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
#get all distinct colour
for color in df['colour'].unique():
    #filter the data for each color and excluding John
    df_temp = df[(df['colour'] == color) & (df['name'] != 'John')] 
    #save into csv file using filename: color_colour.csv
    df_temp.to_csv(color.lower() + '_colour.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: And where I have to declare all the values of colour? Before the for loop? Is the "a" letter at the end of the code also a part of it? Thx for the response

Comment: no need to declare all values of colour. All values are in this set(df.colour).  The letter a at the end is removed.

Comment: @user3365807 Seems this should do that for you

Comment: Great answer, I would only suggest 2 things: `df.colour` should be `df['colour']` both to avoid confusion with your other column calls and for best practice; and `df['colour'].unique()` runs in just under half the time compared to `set(df['colour'])` and uses a built-in method, also best practice

Comment: @G.Anderson; thanks for your comments. Answer updated.

Comment: Thx all for the response. Really appreciate it the support. I will try it out and let you know when it is done

Comment: Hi @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ, I tried to run the code but I am getting an error when reading the file. I tried to run an example of reading with pandas but is the same error. I pasted it above. Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: the file that you are reading is not found on this directory: /home/usrlogr/.  Instead, you can put that csv file where you run your notebook.

Comment: Hi @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ I have run it and it works perfectly. Just one last question: Is there a posibility to filter the lines that are saved with another conditional value. I would ike to save the same column but, for example, I don´t want to be saved the rows that have in the column name, the value "John". Do you know how it would be done? Thx again for all your support. You have really helped me

Comment: @user3365807; you can filter more rows on this code:  df_temp = df[(df['colour'] == color) and (df['name'] == 'John']

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ I have tried the code but it happens the next                  ```error:File "excel.py", line 7, in <module>
    df_temp = df[(df['colour'] == color) and (df['name'] != 'John')]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1478, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().```
Do you know how to fix it? Thx

Comment: Just tried and it worked perfectly. Thx man! Sometimes heroes doesn't wear capes ;)

Comment: glad to help @user3365807